# Predicate for Core Data relationship entities where ALL Foo == NO

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I was wondering how I get all relationship objects matching a BOOL value.

Creating a predicate with ANY works fine:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY journeyPart.lastPart == NO"];
```

But if I try this I just get a crash:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL journeyPart.lastPart == NO"];
```

Thanks

Carl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem, and it looks like a Core Data bug to me. As a workaround, your can replace

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL journeyPart.lastPart == NO"]
```

by the equivalent

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(journeyPart, $x, $x.lastPart != NO).@count = 0"]
```

which works correctly in my test app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this... it had me puzzled for quite a while and I didn't know the SQL syntax

Comment: @CarlT: You are welcome. But SUBQUERY is not SQL syntax, but [poorly documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:) NSExpression/NSPredicate syntax.

Comment: ... ah very interesting... Ill take a close look :)